# Same inputid in 2 conditionalPanel - Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a Shiny newbie and was trying to get something simple working, but unable to :(

Here is a part of my **ui.R**

```
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(

    radioButtons("market",
                 "Choose a Region to build the Sales file:",
                 c("North America & ANZ" = "NA", "Europe" = "EU"), inline = TRUE),

    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.market == 'NA'",
      radioButtons("Locale",
                   "Choose a locale to see the sales Calendar:",
                   c("US and Canada" = "US_CA", "ANZ" = "ANZ"), inline = TRUE),

      numericInput("sale_num", "Choose a Sale Number from the Table below",1,width = '100px' )

    ),

    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.market == 'EU'",
      radioButtons("Locale",
                   "Choose a locale to see the sales Calendar:",
                   c("UK" = "UK", "FR and RoE" = "FR_ROE","DE,AT & CH" = "DACH"), inline = TRUE),
      numericInput("sale_num", "Choose a Sale Number from the Table below",1,width = '100px' )),


    dataTableOutput("sales"))

  ),
```

Here is my  **server.R**

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
       output$sales <- renderDataTable({
       saleTable(input$Locale)
       },options = list(autoWidth = FALSE,searching = FALSE,pageLength=10))
 })
```

When a change in the `market` radio button is triggered, the `Locale` radio does not update and hence the `sales` output table still has stale values and is not reflected by any change in `Locale` values.

I know I'm supposed to use something like `UpdateRadiobuttons`, but I'm not sure how. :(

`saleTable` is just a function in my Rscript that produces a data table.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add session to your server function and run an observeEvent() with the update input function as a result of the event.  Something like this (not tested since I don't have your function):  `server <- shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {
       output$sales <- renderDataTable({
       saleTable(input$Locale)
       },options = list(autoWidth = FALSE,searching = FALSE,pageLength=10))
  observeEvent(input$market, {updateRadioButtons(session, "Locale", choices = c("US and Canada" = "US_CA", "ANZ" = "ANZ"))}) })` Or something like that.

Comment: @RyanMorton Thank you for your reply. But it still doesn't seem to work. :( 
the `input$Locale` value still isn't changing when I select a new value for `input$market`. 
The R function just returns a data table by reading from excel based of the value in `input$Locale`

Comment: I took a closer looker at your UI.  I suggest making the radio button a reactive UI using renderUI().  That way the inputs update and so should the table.  Alternatively, you might consider two different inputs and two different output tables.  In fact, that might be easier at this point.  Generally, I'd avoid re-using an input label in different parts of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Please post a minimal example, i.e. your function saleTable. Don't use the same input ID twice in your app, it's bad style and will not work in most cases. Here are two solutions: First one is bad style, second one better style.

1) Rename the second `Locale` to `Locale2` and put this in your `output$sales`:

```
output$sales <- renderDataTable({    
    if(input$market == 'NA') data <- input$Locale
    else if(input$market=="EU") data <- input$Locale2
    saleTable(data)
    }, options = list(autoWidth = FALSE,searching = FALSE,pageLength=10))
)
```

2) Create the second output as UIOutput and make it dependent on the first one:

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(      
          radioButtons("market",
                   "Choose a Region to build the Sales file:",
                   c("North America & ANZ" = "NA", "Europe" = "EU"), inline = TRUE),      
      uiOutput("Locale")),      
      mainPanel(dataTableOutput("sales"))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Locale <- renderUI({
    if(input$market == "NA") myChoices <-  c("US and Canada" = "US_CA", "ANZ" = "ANZ")
    else myChoices <- c("UK" = "UK", "FR and RoE" = "FR_ROE","DE,AT & CH" = "DACH")

  radioButtons("Locale","Choose a locale to see the sales Calendar:",
                choices <- myChoices,
                 inline = TRUE)
  })
  output$sales <- renderDataTable({
    saleTable(input$Locale)
  },options = list(autoWidth = FALSE,searching = FALSE,pageLength=10))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the expressed interest in using `updateRadioButtons`, I put together a simple example with two radio buttons and a table output.

The first radio button input does not change. The second radio button input depends on the value of the first input. The table displayed is the `mtcars` data frame filtered by the values of the two radio button groups.

Using `observeEvent` ensures the value of the `carb` radio input updates each time the `cyl` radio input is changed. This will also trigger when the application is first launched and is why we do not see the default, dummy, choice `"will be replaced"` for the `carb` radio input.

Make sure to include `session` as one of the Shiny server function arguments. All of Shiny's `update*Input` functions require you pass a `session` object to them.

I hope this proves useful.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 4,
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "cyl",
          label =  "Choose number of cylinders:",
          choices = unique(mtcars$cyl),
          selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)[1]
        ),
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "carb",
          label = "Choose number of carburetors:",
          choices = "will be replaced"
        )
      ),
      column(
        width = 8,
        tableOutput(
          outputId = "mtcars"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$cyl, {
      newChoices <- sort(unique(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == input$cyl, ]$carb))

      updateRadioButtons(
        session = session,
        inputId = "carb",
        choices = newChoices,
        selected = newChoices[1]
      )
    })

    output$mtcars <- renderTable({
      req(input$cyl, input$carb)

      mtcars[mtcars$cyl == input$cyl & mtcars$carb == input$carb, ]
    })
  }
)
```